# How to combine columns in a layout (colspan feature)

Tags: python, qt, layout, pyqt, pyqt5

I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys    

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        label_1 = QLabel("label 1")
        layout.addWidget(label_1, 0, 0)

        label_2 = QLabel("label 2")
        layout.addWidget(label_2, 0, 1)

        label_3 = QLabel("label 3")
        layout.addWidget(label_3, 1, 0)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

screen = Window()
screen.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have this result:

[image: image example of current code]

but I need this:

[image: image example of code which I need]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fourth and fifth arguments of [addWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-2) allow you to specify how many rows and columns to span:

```
label_3 = QLabel("label 3")
layout.addWidget(label_3, 1, 0, 1, 2)
```

Comment: Could you tell me how I can change this setting after adding the widget? I want add it as in first post, and then change colspan

Comment: @ValueError. Please ask a new question, explaining what you are trying to achieve by doing this, as there may be better solutions available.

Answer (score 2):

This is the example code for layout the QLabel. It is PyQt4, but you can try with PyQt5 with small changes.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Window (QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):        

        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.verticalLayout     = QtGui.QVBoxLayout (self)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName ('verticalLayout')

        self.gridLayout         = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName ('gridLayout')

        self.label_1 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label_1.setObjectName('label_1')
        self.label_1.setText ('Label_1')         
        self.label_1.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(182, 182, 182);')

        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label_2.setObjectName('label_2')
        self.label_2.setText ('Label_2')        
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(182, 182, 182);')

        self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label_3.setObjectName('label_3')
        self.label_3.setText ('Label_3')
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(182, 182, 182);')


        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_3, 1, 0, 1, 2)  

        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout)
        self.resize(300, 100)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```